# How to prove H → M ￢H → ￢M prove H↔M?

Tags: fitch

I'm using the program Fitch and I need to make a formal proof for this:

1. H → M
2. ￢H → ￢M

Prove: H↔M

Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the user!

Comment: Hello, it might be difficult to get homework help unless you shown you have put some effort into it and tried some things. [Here's a good example.](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/54175/given-p-%e2%87%92-q-and-m-%e2%87%92-p-%e2%88%a8-q-use-the-fitch-system-to-prove-m-%e2%87%92-q?rq=1).

Comment: See also [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37405/fitch-proof-lpl-exercise-8-17)

Comment: what is an idea? sorry, you're using language in a highly imprecise way here

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

Normally I keep my nose out of logic especially, but this one is straightforward, so I'll give you a clue.

Note, that in this argument, you have a conclusion which is the biconditional. The biconditional's definition requires two criteria be met, and ONE of the two premises in the argument satisfies it. The other doesn't, but I'm suggesting you might want to write out the inverse, converse, and contrapositive of both premises and see how they relate to the definition of the biconditional.

Once you find the two premises to satisfy the definition of the biconditional, you should be all set!

Good luck.

Comment: I think it would be best at this point to just give your answer.

Answer (score 0):

????

(H --> H) --> M

H --> M

(H --> -H) <--> (M <--> -H)

(-H --> -H) --> --H

-H --> H

(-H --> -M) <--> (-M <--> H)

(H --> M --> -H --> H --> -M) --> (H <--> M)

Comment: What does "????" mean?

Comment: Thought I am not entirely sure about, as in "question it".

Answer (score 0):

You have `H → M` as one premise, so deriving `M → H` will allow you to introduce the biconditional.  So introduce that conditional the usual way (aka via a conditional proof).

```
|  H → M       Premise
|_ ¬H → ¬M     Premise
|  |_ M        Assumption
|  |  :
|  |  H
|  M → H      Conditional Introduction
|  H ↔ M      Biconditional Introduction
```

The steps between the assumption of M and the derivation of H should not be hard.  Looking at the second premise will be helpful.

Comment: How is H not also an assumption?

Comment: Because you are *not* assuming `H`, you are aiming to *derive* it from the assumption of `M`.   **However** you can do that by making another assumption

Comment: And we are deriving M from an assumption of H: H ---> M.  It ends up being recursive assumptions at best.

Comment: No we are *not* deriving `M` from any prior statement; we *are* raising it as an assumption in a new context.

Comment: Premise: H --> M.

Comment: Yes, but we are not deriving `M` from that (indeed we cannot).

Comment: M is the result of H, where --> means "tends towards", "therefore", or however you want to word it.  Yeah, M ---> H is observing M as an assumption, but it goes both ways.

Comment: `H→ M` says "`M` is a consequence of `H`", so we *cannot* derive `M` *unless* we also have `H`, which we do not.  Thus we can only *assume* it, make derivations *in context* of that assumption, and close the context by properly *discharging* the assumption (in this case with the rule of *Conditional Introduction*, thereby *deriving* `M→H`).

Comment: Yet H as a propostion is also assumed.  H if and only if M, necessitate H as an element of M where M simulataneously exists if and only if H considering the identity of M contains H.  H as a propostion is assumed, hence H is assumed.

Comment: We are **not** assuming `H` anywhere!  No subproof has been raised with an assumption of `H`.

Comment: Tell me how H is not assumed if that is how the premise begins as H --> M.  I am not trying to disagree for the sake of disagreeing, but H results in M, but H is a proposition.  Take for example: H --> M requires (H-->H) implicitly as an identity property.  The statement requires an assumed identity.

Comment: `H` is the **antecedent** of the conditional statement `H → M`.  The words are not synonyms.

Comment: Antecedent: a thing or event which exists prior.  Yes, but as an antecedent it begins as an assumed proposition.  I don't know which words you are referring too when you state "synonyms".

Comment: In the Fitch System of Natural Deduction an **assumption** is a statement raised (without needing to be derived) to start a *context* of contingent derivations (aka a subproof).  That is all that it is.

Comment: Then to start a context, we are left with the antecedent being an assumption...unless you claim it does not start the context.